# How to change HTML range input value with C# Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium

I want to chance the value of a HTML input range with C# Selenium. Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oeH8.jpg).

Here's is the input range.

`<input type="range" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1" name ="scale" id="scale" value="0.9"></input>`

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy the code, [edit] your question and past the code. Please also post a [repro].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the attribute of an element using javascript

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver);
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('scale').setAttribute('max', '10')");
```

I am changing the attribute 'max', but you can change whichever attribute you want with the desired value.

More information on using javascript with selenium can be found here:  https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html